# Custom Font Not supporting in Android Device

Tags: android, android-widget

Hi am developing One Android App in which am using Custom font .TTF file.The problem is i tested with same Branded Device with Different Build Version.the Older Version Device supporting Custom Font But new version Device not taking Custom Font.

Comment: Not a downvoter. Post some code related to your Custom Font.

Comment: I don't know the answer that fast, but it would help a little if I (we) know the versions you are using.

Answer (score 1):

i have one suggestion add those font in assets and make your text in html thus you can add it in Web View android 
 Hope it will work for your case:

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
        view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);     
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo/intro.html");
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.introLayout1)).addView(view);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

first download the needed the ttf file (Font style which you want ). and put that it in the **assets** folder in android project.  then add the following code in java file..

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Eltpan-n.ttf");
        txt.setTypeface(font);
```

hope it will help you.. its worked like a charm for me .. if you satisfied vote for my answer